# How I see the Model in a post method MVC Spring

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

This `view` receives data, and I add this data in the model because I need this information in the next `view` (I need `consultaUrgente`):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pagoTarjeta.htm")
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, 
HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestParam Map<String, String> reqPar) throws ServletException, 
IOException {
String titulo = reqPar.get("titulo");
    String descripcion = reqPar.get("descripcion");
    Integer ServiceId = Integer.parseInt(reqPar.get("servicio"));
    Servicio servicioConsulta = servicioManager.getServiciobyId(ServiceId);
    ConsultaUrgente consultaUrgente = new ConsultaUrgente();
    Cliente cliente = clienteManager.getClientes().get(0);
    consultaUrgente.setDescripcion(descripcion);
    consultaUrgente.setTitulo(titulo);

    consultaUrgente.setServicioOrigen(servicioConsulta);
    consultaUrgente.setClienteOrigen(cliente);
    consultaUrgente.setEstado(EstadoConsulta.creada);

    Map<String, Object> myModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    myModel.put("consultaUrgente", consultaUrgente);
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("pagoTarjeta", "model", myModel);

    return mav;
}
```

In the next view when I press a button I came to this post method. And here I need the data that I added previously to the model .

```
@PostMapping("/pagoTarjeta.htm")
protected ModelAndView onSubmit(@RequestParam Map<String, String> reqPar, 
ModelAndView modelAndView)
        throws Exception {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the data you placed within the model, is used by the "pagoTarjeta" view. If you wish to use that data in another controller then you should use the `@ModelAttribute` annotation, using @ModelAttribute simply pulls the value from the session and passes it in as a parameter to another controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pagoTarjeta.htm")
public String handleRequest(
       HttpServletRequest request, 
       HttpServletResponse response,
       @RequestParam Map<String, String> reqPar, 
       Model model) 
throws ServletException, IOException {

     String titulo = reqPar.get("titulo");
     String descripcion = reqPar.get("descripcion");
     Integer ServiceId = Integer.parseInt(reqPar.get("servicio"));
     Servicio servicioConsulta = servicioManager.getServiciobyId(ServiceId);
     ConsultaUrgente consultaUrgente = new ConsultaUrgente();
     Cliente cliente = clienteManager.getClientes().get(0);
     consultaUrgente.setDescripcion(descripcion);
     consultaUrgente.setTitulo(titulo);

     consultaUrgente.setServicioOrigen(servicioConsulta);
     consultaUrgente.setClienteOrigen(cliente);
     consultaUrgente.setEstado(EstadoConsulta.creada);

     model.addAtribute("consultaUrgente", consultaUrgente); // Add consultaUrgentre as an attribute to the model

     return "pagoTarjeta"; // Pass the model to the view
}


@PostMapping("/pagoTarjeta.htm")
protected ModelAndView onSubmit(@ModelAttribute("consultaUrgente") ConsultaUrgente consultaUrgent, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception 
{
     // Retrieve the the object here.
}
```

And you can use the `ConsultaUrgente` object from the model and pass it to another view as wish.